WIX - Uninstall .NET 8 from bundle
I try to install and uninstall .NET 8 in my application. But I have a problem. Everything is good, aplication install and uninstall but I have problem with uninstall .NET Runtime and ASP.NET Core. After installation .NET is staying.
When I try uninstall .NET manually(By powershell) by for example ./aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe /uninstall /quiet /norestart dotnet is removed without any problem.
This is my Bundle.wxs
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  
  <?include APIVariables.wxi ?>
  <Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)"
          Version="$(var.InstallerVersion)"
          Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.APIUpgradeCode)"
          Copyright="$(var.CopyrightStatement)"
          >
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        ShowVersion="yes"
      />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>

      <ExePackage
        Name="vcredist_x64_14.29.30139.exe"
        SourceFile="vcredist_x64_14.29.30139.exe"
        InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet /norestart"
        Vital="yes" />

      <ExePackage
        Name="dotnet-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe"
        SourceFile="dotnet-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe"
        InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet /norestart"
        Vital="yes" />

      <ExePackage
        Name="aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe"
        SourceFile="aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.6-win-x64.exe"
        InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet /norestart"
        Vital="yes" />

      
      <MsiPackage
        Name="RabbitMQ.Installer.msi"
        SourceFile="$(var.RabbitMQ.Installer.TargetDir)RabbitMQ.Installer.msi"
        Vital="yes"
        Visible="no"
        Cache="no"
      />
      
      <MsiPackage
        Name="WAA.API.msi"
        SourceFile="$(var.WAA.API.InstallModule.TargetDir)WAA.API.msi"
        Vital="yes"
        Visible="no"
        Cache="no"
      />
      
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>

How to uninstall .NET by WIX ? You have any ideas ?

You are missing DetectCondition attributes on your ExePackage element. That means the Burn engine has no way to determine if the exe-based installer is installed. Therefore, the exe-based installers always look absent and there is nothing to do on uninstall.
If you look in the log file, you'll see the package states in the section where Burn plans the packages.
